# Pronunciation of "Иванов"

Tags: произношение, выбор-имени, ударение

What is the correct way to stress the Russian surname Иванов? I have seen both Ивано́в and Ива́нов.

Comment: These are two different surnames which are stressed differently. You should stress and pronounce surnames the way the surname bearer does it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Ивано́в` is much more common although some Ivanovs prefer to be called `Ива́нов`.

There is also the possessive adjective `ива́нов` (Ivan's): `Ива́нов день` (Kupala Night).

Comment: No, wrong! "Ива́нов" is not surname, see Arioch's answer!

Answer (score 4):

I would say, if you are sure Ива́нов is a surname - then it most probably not Russian one but some West-Slavic (Bulgarian?).

And even more probable, that Ива́нов was not surname, it was a genitive case of plural of Иван first name.

- Ива́н => Ива́ны => Ива́нов
- John => Johns => of Johns

UPD by Yellow Sky: Ива́нов can also be a nominative case singular possessive adjective (John's), like мамин, Серёжин, etc. Cf. "Ива́нов день".

Comment: `West-Slavic (Bulgarian?)` Bulgarian is South Slavic.
`Ива́нов was not surname, it was a genitive case` The same applies to Ивано́в as well.

Comment: @Matt nope, Ивано́в would not be plural genitive from Ива́н in Russian. Apart from Gorbachev-speak. Maybe it will in other Slavonic languages.

Comment: Nah, I mean it's a possessive adjective. Language and stress don't matter.

Comment: that can be, I guess

Comment: But why only plural? Ива́нов can also be a nominative case _singular_ possessive adjective, like мамин, Серёжин, etc. Cf. "Ива́нов день".

Comment: @Matt - there are few cases in Russian when stressing exactly is used to tell apart two ambiguous words. I believe Иванов is the case.

Comment: [Всеволод Ива́нов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2,_%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%92%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)